# check if file exists (case-sensitive)

Tags: node.js, operating-system, case-sensitive

Is there a way to check whether a file exists in NodeJS, with case-sensitivity, *even when the underlying file system isn't case sensitive*?

[fs.exists()](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) may or may not be case sensitive depending on the underlying file system.

```
 fs = require('fs');
 fs.existsSync('readme.txt') // true
 fs.existsSync('README.TXT') // false (or true, depending on the file system)
```

This causes problems when developing an app on a case-insensitive development environment that will be deployed on a case-sensitive server. I recently had an issue where the build was broken by a typo. It worked locally.

If I can get Node to tell me, "yes, `README.TXT` exists, and it's stored as `readme.txt`" that will be enough to solve the problem.

Comment: I think a http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_realpathsync_path_cache would do the trick (though you'd likely want to try catch wrap it since it can throw)

Comment: you could try to do readdir first - afaik on osx it returns names in original case

Comment: @generalhenry Good thought. Unfortunately it returns the same case as the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can't comment < 50 rep I'll make a new post.

@patrik's solution was working nice except on windows because of the root check

I changed it to look like following:

```
function fileExistsWithCaseSync (filepath) {
  var dir = path.dirname(filepath)
  if (dir === path.dirname(dir)) {
    return true
  }
  var filenames = fs.readdirSync(dir)
  if (filenames.indexOf(path.basename(filepath)) === -1) {
    return false
  }
  return fileExistsWithCaseSync(dir)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Following [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/705115/andrey-sidorov)'s suggestion I implemented a function that uses readdir.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

function fileExistsWithCaseSync(filepath) {
    var dir = path.dirname(filepath);
    if (dir === '/' || dir === '.') return true;
    var filenames = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    if (filenames.indexOf(path.basename(filepath)) === -1) {
        return false;
    }
    return fileExistsWithCaseSync(dir);
}

console.log(fileExistsWithCaseSync(__dirname + '/README.txt')) // false
console.log(fileExistsWithCaseSync(__dirname + '/readme.txt')) // true
```

I wouldn't use this function in production because each call makes several synchronous trips to the filesystem. But it's good enough for my needs: preventing my local development server from serving `Foo.js` when the file is actually called `foo.js` (which won't work in production).

Answer (score 2):

Just to help someone who having this path problem.

The [Patric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/437/patrick-mcelhaney)'s function pretty works for this case, but not solve the path issue. I found the [true path module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/true-case-path) that actually solved my problem with case-sensitive paths on linux (ubuntu).

See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086985/how-to-obtain-case-exact-path-of-a-file-in-node-js-on-windows).

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

function fileExistsWithCaseSync(filepath) {
    var dir = path.dirname(filepath);
    if (filepath=== '/' || filepath=== '.') return true;
    var filenames = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    if (filenames.indexOf(path.basename(filepath)) === -1) {
        return false;
    }
    return fileExistsWithCaseSync(dir);
}

console.log(fileExistsWithCaseSync('./README.txt')) // false
console.log(fileExistsWithCaseSync('./readme.txt')) // true
```

check `filepath` use fileExistsWithCaseSync no `__dirname`